# Call Model Method In Controller In Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Hello Friends I am new to Yii2 Framework.

i am writing following code as specified in mention filename still....

While i am calling model method then does not showing output showing **500 error** in console

Is Any Mistake in code then please mention here ..

**SiteController.php**

```
<?php

use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\data\Pagination;
use app\models\Site;

class SiteController extends CController
{
    // Define an action. actionIndex is a default action
    public function actionIndex()
    {   
        $data =  Site::models()->getData();    
        $this->render('view',array(
        'data'=>$data,
        ));

        // $this->render('view');
        }
  }
```

**Site.php - Model**

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

    class Site extends ActiveRecord
    {
        public function getData() {
              $connection = Yii::app()->db;
              $command = $connection->createCommand("Select * from site");
              return $caterow = $command->queryAll();
        }
        public static function tableName()
        {
            return 'site';
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is this `CController`? Typo? It's not Yii 1.

Comment: i m using netbeans and when press ctrl+spacebar. it showing list of classes with starting with 'C'. so when i run this simple with without 'C' then does not run program and if use 'CController' then its run proper

Comment: its not yii means what ?

Comment: But does this SiteController work? Have you got file with `CController` class in the same folder? I can not see `use` statement with it. If it's error you should change `CController` to `Controller`.

Comment: just problem shorted out problem was from model i had to initialize parent i am sharing this code. tnx for reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hello friends, First Thanks to all to help me 
now i am sharing this code this is complete now work in mycase.**

**i had sorted out this problem with following code.
Try this one now its completely work**

**main.php**

```
    <?php

// This is the main config file
// You should avoid placing configuration everywhere else
return array(
    // We have to enable Yii to load all the files we created
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.views.*',
                'application.components.*'
    ),

    // We set up SQLite database connection. It's a simple database
    // which does not require a separae server
    'components'=>array(
        'db'=>array(
            'class'=>'CDbConnection',
            'connectionString'=>'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=student',
            'username'=>'root',
            'password'=>'',
            'emulatePrepare'=>true,
            ),
    )
);
```

**SiteController.php**

```
<?php

class SiteController extends CController
{
    /**
     * Lists all models.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
                $s = new Site();
                $a = $s->getData();
        $this->render('view',array('a'=>$a));
    }

}
```

**Site.php - Model**

```
<?php

class Site extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @return static the static model class
     */
    public static function model()
    {
        return parent::model('Site');
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'site';
    }

        public function getData(){
            return $result =  Site::model()->find();
        }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

call your method without `models()`

```
$data =  Site::getData();
```

Comment: i tried it still getting same error if i will comment this line then just render view it is showing output.

Comment: is any mistake in model

Comment: i think problem syntax of model please compare models create using gii and your model

Comment: change Yii::app()->db to Yii::$app->db in model

Comment: yh you are right problem was in that model code (syntax). just shorted out that one thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

SiteController.php :

```
  $data =  Site::getData();
```

Site.php (Model) :Make sure that function is static

```
public static function getData() {

    return "anything";
}
```

Comment: hello mohan i m doing as you written above still not working. i had putted your method code.

Comment: my table name also : site . if i write code in controller then getting record but using model its not working

Comment: Update   $connection = Yii::$app->db;     not $connection = Yii::app()->db; this is yii 1st syntax and u 'r using yii2

Comment: yes it is yii2. just shorted out all the problem with that model file code syntax i had updated answer code. i hope this will help all. tnx for help